# how to increase "expires_in" time of a access token in Oauth_provider_toolkit Django rest_framework?

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

how to   increase expires_in time of access token (by default it is 36000 i) in Oauth_provider toolkit django rest framework django 
 i want to  increase the time so i need help .

should i change the django rest framework code  or  there is any method available previously so i can use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set in your settings:

```
 OAUTH2_PROVIDER = {
        'ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 60 * 15,
        'OAUTH_SINGLE_ACCESS_TOKEN': True,
        'OAUTH_DELETE_EXPIRED': True
 }
```

This will set your expire time to 15 minutes.
The second and third constants are optional, only to show what you can do.

You can override all of these:

```
DEFAULTS = {
    'CLIENT_ID_GENERATOR_CLASS': 'oauth2_provider.generators.ClientIdGenerator',
    'CLIENT_SECRET_GENERATOR_CLASS': 'oauth2_provider.generators.ClientSecretGenerator',
    'CLIENT_SECRET_GENERATOR_LENGTH': 128,
    'OAUTH2_SERVER_CLASS': 'oauthlib.oauth2.Server',
    'OAUTH2_VALIDATOR_CLASS': 'oauth2_provider.oauth2_validators.OAuth2Validator',
    'OAUTH2_BACKEND_CLASS': 'oauth2_provider.oauth2_backends.OAuthLibCore',
    'SCOPES': {"read": "Reading scope", "write": "Writing scope"},
    'DEFAULT_SCOPES': ['__all__'],
    'READ_SCOPE': 'read',
    'WRITE_SCOPE': 'write',
    'AUTHORIZATION_CODE_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 60,
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': 36000,
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRE_SECONDS': None,
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKEN': True,
    'APPLICATION_MODEL': getattr(settings, 'OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL', 'oauth2_provider.Application'),
    'REQUEST_APPROVAL_PROMPT': 'force',
    'ALLOWED_REDIRECT_URI_SCHEMES': ['http', 'https'],

    # Special settings that will be evaluated at runtime
    '_SCOPES': [],
    '_DEFAULT_SCOPES': [],
}
```